# How to deploy multiple reactjs applications on server?

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I'm new to reactjs. I have some doubts on deploying react js on server. 
 Lets say, I have 2 react js build folders (admin panel, frontend) and one nodejs folder for backend. 
Is it possible to put/deploy all the three in same domain with different ports ?

For ex.,

Frontend - https://example.com/login (proxy configured) , port : 4200 
Admin panel - https://example.com:5200/adminpanel , port : 5200 
Backend (node) - https://example.com:8443/api/something , port : 8443

Or any other efficient way to deploy ?

Answer (score 1):

Deploy all three apps and use nginx

```
location /adminpanel{
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5200/adminpanel;
        }
location ~ ^/api/?(.*){
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8443/api/$1;
        }
# root mapping
location /{
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:4200/login;
        }
```